# Creating Docker network bridge to route outgoing traffic via specific interface

Tags: networking, routing, iptables, docker

I am trying to create new docker network bridge that route outgoing traffic via my 2nd network interface, I managed to make containers traffic go through the desired interface, however i lost the ability to communicate with the container from the localhost, and likewise from inside the container. Here is the configuration so far.

My Network interfaces:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.1.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.1.255

docker_backup: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
```

Docker network bridge configuration

```json
[
    {
        "Name": "docker_backup",
        "Id": "5252a641d2087e5d4ed6aa142327a3193c2142d8fe5cac6b6a163d0154819d6d",
        "Created": "2021-11-19T16:36:37.037180993+03:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "false",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker_backup"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

cat /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

```
#
# reserved values
#
255     local
254     main
253     default
0       unspec
#
# local
#
#1      inr.ruhep
1 docker_backup
```

iptables

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
SNAT       all  --  172.18.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0            to:10.0.1.3
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.19.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.23.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.18.0.3           172.18.0.3           tcp dpt:80

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.1            tcp dpt:8081 to:172.18.0.3:80
```

Routes and ip tables

```sh
ip rule add from 172.18.0.0/16 tab docker_backup
ip route add 172.18.0.0/16 dev eth1 tab docker_backup
ip route add default via 10.0.1.1 dev eth1 tab docker_backup
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.0/16 ! -o docker_backup -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.1.3
```

netstat -an | grep 'LISTEN '

```
# netstat -an | grep 'LISTEN '
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3493          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8081          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5938            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 10.0.1.3:8083           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5941          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 10.0.1.3:6881           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

route

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         homerouter.cpe  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
10.0.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 eth1
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth1
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker_backup
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-3271a2013d45
172.23.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-1855923fbb3f
```

docker-compose example

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
    tester:
        image: linuxserver/nginx
        environment:
            - TZ=Asia/Kuwait
        volumes:
            - ./config:/config
        ports:
            - 127.0.0.1:8081:80
        networks:
            docker_backup:
                ipv4_address: 172.18.0.3
networks:
    docker_backup:
        external: true
```

from the bastion host curl attempts:

```bsh
(07:27:55) root@server.local ~/tests
# curl -v localhost:8081
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8081...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8081 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8081
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
(07:28:10) root@server.local ~/tests
# curl -v 172.18.0.3:80
*   Trying 172.18.0.3:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 172.18.0.3 port 80 failed: No route to host
* Failed to connect to 172.18.0.3 port 80: No route to host
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.18.0.3 port 80: No route to host
```

from inside the container im able to connect to the outside world using eth1 IP address

```bsh
root@50ed3e196cde:/# curl -LSs ifconfig.io
37.xx.xxx.xx
```

route & ifconfig & ping to container gateway.

```
root@434d48b82d6a:/# route

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         server          0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.18.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0

root@434d48b82d6a:/# ping -W 5 172.18.0.1

PING 172.18.0.1 (172.18.0.1): 56 data bytes
--- 172.18.0.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss

root@434d48b82d6a:/# ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:AC:12:00:03
          inet addr:172.18.0.3  Bcast:172.18.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
```

however any attempts to ping any other docker or main host ip i.e. (local addresses) fails.

```bsh
root@50ed3e196cde:/# curl -v --connect-timeout 5 172.18.0.1
*   Trying 172.18.0.1:80...
* After 5000ms connect time, move on!
* connect to 172.18.0.1 port 80 failed: Operation timed out
* Connection timeout after 5000 ms
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Connection timeout after 5000 ms
```

i can ping the container ip from the main host, but i cannot access any service exposed.

```
# ping 172.18.0.3
PING 172.18.0.3 (172.18.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.18.0.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.095 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.074 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.3: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.092 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.3: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.086 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.3: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.087 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.3: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.089 ms
^C
--- 172.18.0.3 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5098ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.074/0.087/0.095/0.006 ms
(07:10:15) root@server.local ~/tests
# ping 172.18.0.3^C
(07:10:19) root@server.local ~/tests
# curl -v http://172.18.0.3:80
*   Trying 172.18.0.3:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 172.18.0.3 port 80 failed: No route to host
* Failed to connect to 172.18.0.3 port 80: No route to host
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.18.0.3 port 80: No route to host
```

So, the question is how would i modify the routes or iptables rules to make the traffic flows from local address to the container and from the container to the local addresses while maintaining the outgoing ip?

Comment: Thanks for the suggesting.. it didn't help solve the problem, i used https://github.com/lucasheld/docker-host-ip/blob/master/run.sh as reference for my attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding new ip rule on main host that route traffic to the container subnet into the main table.

```
ip rule add to 172.18.0.0/16 lookup main priority 10
```

Comment: What does this do / it didn't help in my case. How does your ip route look like? What is main in this context?

Comment: Not sure what you mean it does not work, i used these following commands to switch specific docker network to another gateway while retaining internal commination
sadly i cannot write out all the info here, you can check out [this link](https://pastebin.mozilla.org/vrBvSMXe) if you are interested.